# Access table data by row index

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a Table in Excel that is laid out as follows. What I require is a way of accessing a table row by index for a calculation.

To be precise, I have been asked to work out an overall coefficient for this table (and many like it). So in this case, the Coefficient would be -

```
=SUM(3*0, 1*2, 3*0, 11*0) / SUBTOTAL(109, [Count])
```

In short, I need a way of getting the total of `[Value]*[Count]` for every row, but without adding an extra column. The table below is an example, and some have more rows, so the solution must be scalable and not explicit, as in my example above.

The trouble is, I don't want to have to explicitly declare the value, but I can't find a way of referencing a column/row index. Is this possible? Thanks.

```
BigHand Mobile - Access                                Value   Count    %
I already use BigHand mobile                           0       3        16.7%
I don't use BigHand mobile, but I would like to        2       1        5.6%
I don't use BigHand mobile, and I do not require it    0       3        16.7%
I don't dictate so do not require it                   0       11       61.1%
Coefficient                                            ???
```

Comment: I don't understand, where does the `109` come from? You can definitely use an array formula or a formula that finds addresses and rows/columns with offset. I'm just not sure what it is that you're looking to pull, explicitly.

Comment: I'll update my question to better ask what is required. FYI, 109 is the SUBTOTAL key for SUM. So `SUBTOTAL(109, (3, 1, 3, 11))` is basically the same as `SUM(3, 1, 3, 11)`, it's just through habit that I use it. Thanks.

Comment: So is the problem that it's dynamic? A `sumproduct` would do what you need, if you defined the arrays like `sumproduct(B:B,C:C)` except your coefficient is in `B`. Where are you hung up? Counting the rows?

Comment: Ah ha, `SUMPRODUCT([value],[count]) / SUBTOTAL(109, [Count])` to the rescue. Thanks for the heads up, I've never come across `SUMPRODUCT()` before (will mark as correct if you add as an answer).

Comment: Yeah, there are some interesting formulas out there that aren't easy to run across when looking!

Comment: Is the same for any language/software that employs function. The bottom line is if you don't know what you are looking for, you'll never find it, and that is why I love sites like this! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [sumproduct](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumproduct-HP005209293.aspx) to get the array multiplication to work.

`=SUMPRODUCT(B:B,C:C) / SUBTOTAL(109,C:C)`

Comment: Great stuff. As noted in the comments to my question, I used `SUMPRODUCT([value],[count]) / SUBTOTAL(109, [Count])` as I was dealing with tables, not standard arrays, but `SUMPRODUCT()` was exactly what I needed. Thanks.